# Prevent ajax-returned javascript from immediate execution

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: "script"
})
```

But returned javascript execute immediately! And I need running only when certain conditions are met, i.e.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(data) {
    if (condition) {
      run returned javascript
    } else {
      do nothing
    }
  }
})
```

I try this, but it doesn't working. What could be wrong and how to solve this problem?

Comment: if (condition) { do ajax request}?

Comment: Сonditions may change while I wait for response

Comment: You could change the data type of the ajax to text, then execute the text manually

Comment: You won’t believe it, but I just thought of it myself
Thanks anyway